# how to import multiple files from aws s3

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple files named in order:

```
prefix 1: 
    axc200101.csv
    axc200102.csv
    ...up until ax200112.csv

prefix 2:
   axc18840407-20191231-01.csv 
   axc18840407-20191231-02.csv
   .. axc18840407-20191231-65.csv
```

They are all in s3. I want to use pandas and import the data all at once. Is there any way to do this?

my current code doesn't return anything. also, it only able to deal with one prefix:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('databucket')
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="data/")

prefix_df = pd.DataFrame()

for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    temp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), encoding='utf8')        
    prefix_df = prefix_df.append(temp)
```

can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code should work. are you sure prefix_objs is not empty?

Comment: maybe try StringIO instead??? that's what I use and works well. On a side note, appending as you read is lot of overhead, create a list of dataframes and pd.concat(the list of dataframes). It'll be faster if you have a lot files

Comment: yeah, the data s3 url is databucket/data/axc200101.csv

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out [dask.dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). It's built for doing exactly what you're talking about, in parallel, leveraging multiple CPUs or a distributed cluster.

```py
import dask.dataframe as ddf

dask_dataframe = ddf.read_csv('s3://aip-genome/data/*.csv')

# if you want to load the data into a pandas DataFrame, call compute()
df = dask_dataframe.compute()
```

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 18 I got this error

Comment: You do need to make sure all the csvs are formatted the same way, and provide args to parse the files correctly. If you need, you can provide a list of file paths rather than a wildcard.